# Slow performance azure linked server

Tags: azure, database-performance, linked-server

I have a lot of data from one server i need to pull down from one server to another server in different tables. Therefore i have created a linked server.

We are talking about to windows azure machines with SQL databases.

But it seems to perform very badly. It  takes over 5 hours to move 8 million rows. Which i think can be done a lot faster.

I have tried to change the Collation Compatible to True, but that did not help. Does anyone have any suggestions? Is it the setup of my machines in azure controlpanel which i should change?

Best regards

Comment: does the same thing happens on non-azure machines?

Comment: Did you specified a Region or an Affinity group when you created the Virtual Machine? If you specified a Region, it is possible that the two VMs have been deployed in different datacenters in the same region which can create latency in network communication between the two machine. Using an affinity group instead forces the two machine to be in the same datacenter. See http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7916.importance-of-windows-azure-affinity-groups.aspx

Comment: Have you attempted to do any analysis to see where your bottlenecks may be? Network saturation? SQL DB performance, etc...  there are a multitude of factors that are at work and any one of them could be the possible cause.

Comment: @trailmax - No it does not - But we do not use linked servers on on-premise servers. And the IO performance is way better on those servers.

Comment: @AndreaColuccio I will try to check that out. We specified a region i know, but i dont know if we use affinity groups.

Comment: @BrentDaCodeMonkey Yes we have- We believe it is an IO problem. Its like sometimes it only transfers data with 4mb pr sek. When we onpremise and without linked-servers and small tables experience at least 130 mb pr sec. But can it be related to large tabes? We have clustered indexes. So it should not be that slow

Comment: two possible areas to look at. 1) Azure VMs are limited to a maximum of 500iops at the disk level (not accounting for any buffering). So to increase performance you need to try and leverage multiple disks. 2) You can expect approximately 100mbs per core for network traffic for both inbound/outbound traffic. So it network IO is a bottleneck, try increasing the size of the VM.

Comment: @BrentDaCodeMonkey - We have also tried this with striping the disks to get maximum IOPS. So maybe it is the Network. :)